# hadn’t felt / hadn’t been feeling (in context)

Tags: past-tense, exam-questions, perfect-constructions

Question with an assignment.

> Instructions: Complete the sentences with the correct forms of the verbs in brackets. Use the Past Simple, Past Perfect Simple, Past Perfect Continuous.
>
> 1. Mum had lunch and then (a) ____ (lie down) for a few minutes as she ____ (not feel) well all day.

I wrote,

> Mum had lunch and then **lay down** for a few minutes as she **hadn’t felt** well all day.

However, I was marked as wrong by my teacher for “hadn’t felt well”. I feel like both are correct. Was I wrong?

Comment: I agree. _Hadn't been feeling well_ would be the most likely, but _hadn't felt well_ would also be perfectly possible.